# audio player issue in this plugin- just_audio: 0.9.35

Tags: flutter, dart

i have issue for just_audio: 0.9.35 this plugin for audio player check the above error and Init 76c2025 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [begoniain, Redmi Note 8 Pro, Xiaomi, 28]
[log] [31m 2 Permission Status PermissionStatus.granted [0m
D/AudioManager(22784): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:614)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (WavExtractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1017)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(22784):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/AudioPlayer(22784): TYPE_SOURCE: None of the available extractors (WavExtractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.

need solution of this error for dart audio player in app using local files like  player.setAsset('assets/audio/card_activation_heart.wav');
player.play();

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).